# Copy files from host to docker container then commit and push

Tags: docker

I'm using docker in Ubuntu. During development phase I cloned all source code from Git in host, edit them in WebStorm, and them run with Node.js inside a docker container with `-v /host_dev_src:/container_src` so that I can test.

Then when I wanted to send them for testing: I committed the container and pushed a new version. But when I pulled and ran the image on the test machine, the source code was missing. That makes sense as in test machine there's no `/host_src` available.

My current workaround is to clone the source code on the test machine and run docker with `-v /host_test_src:/container_src`. But I'd like to know if it's possible to copy the source code directly into the container and avoid that manipulation.  I'd prefer to just copy, paste and run the image file with the source code, especially since there's no Internet connection on our testing machines.

PS: Seems `docker cp` only supports copying file from container to host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to have a git clone step in the Dockerfile which adds the source code into the image. During development, you can override this code with your `-v` argument to `docker run` so that you can make changes without rebuilding. When it comes to testing, you just check your changes in and build a new image. Now you have a fully standalone alone image for testing.

Note that if you have a `VOLUME` instruction in your Dockerfile, you will need to make sure it occurs after the git clone step.

The problem with this approach is that if you are using a compiled language, you only want your binaries to live in the final image. In this case, the git clone needs to be replaced with some code that either fetches or compiles the binaries.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about VOLUME order.  I always assumed you can't write to volumes from a Dockerfile because I only tried the VOLUME step first (which seems more logical to me).

Comment: Yeah, volumes are pretty subtle. It makes sense when you understand how they work. My blog might help http://container-solutions.com/2014/12/understanding-volumes-docker/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: how to copy files and then commit the new container/image? Using -v and REbuilding every time is one approach, but not to the question asked.

Comment: @so860 I answered the question by suggesting a better workflow that achieved what the asker wanted. To answer your question, docker cp now works in both directions I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Please treat your source codes are data, then package them as data container , see https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

**Step 1** Create `app_src` docker image

Put one `Dockerfile` inside your git repo like

```
FROM BUSYBOX
ADD . /container_src
VOLUME /container_src
```

Then you can build source image like

```
docker build -t app_src .
```

During development period, you can always use your old solution `-v /host_dev_src:/container_src`.

**Step 2 Transfer this docker image like app image**

You can transfer this `app_src` image to test system similar to your application image, probably via docker registry

**Step 3 Run as data container**

In test system, run `app` container above it. (I use `ubuntu` for demo)

```
docker run -d -v /container_src --name code app_src
docker run -it --volumes-from code ubuntu bash
root@dfb2bb8456fe:/# ls /container_src
Dockerfile  hello.c
root@dfb2bb8456fe:/#
```

Hope it gives help

(give credits to https://github.com/toffer/docker-data-only-container-demo , which I get detail ideas)

Comment: so you still do not carry the source files with the container and the testers should get image separately and the sources separately

Comment: packaging source code inside app image is also good solution for internal delivery (a.k.a debug version). I try to separate it here.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Adrian's answer, I do git clone, and then do

```
CMD git pull && start-my-service
```

so the latest code at the checked out branch gets run.  This is obviously not for everyone, but it works in some software release models.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and have two Dockerfiles. The `base` one would know how to run your app from a predevined folder, but *not* declare it a volume. When developing you will be running this container with your host folder mounted as a volume. Another one, the `package` one, will inherit the `base` one and copy/add the files from your host directory, again without volumes, so that you would carry all the files to the tester's host.

Comment: The `package` Dockerfile will probably have to sit at the root of your `host_dev_src` to be able to take the files from your host fs.